# Depth First Search is causing a StackOverFlowError

Tags: java, static-methods, depth-first-search

I have an assignment were I have to create run a depth first search through a directed graph, and return the traversal as a linked list. I believe the code for the DFS is correct as it seems to match up with the text book, and as I walk through the steps it makes sense. If I print it out as each vertex gets marked, it keeps printer over and over causing the stack overflow error.

```
 private static boolean[] marked;
 private static LinkedList<Integer> ret;

 public static LinkedList<Integer> dfs(Digraph g, int s) {

     marked = new boolean[g.V()];

    ret = new LinkedList<>();

    marked[s] = true;
    System.out.print(s);

    ret.add(s);



   for (int i : g.adj(s)) {
       if (!marked[i]) {
          dfs(g, i);

     }
   }

   return ret;
  }
```

My guess would be the boolean[] marked is reseting every time I call dfs. I tried putting that outside the method but because the method is static and I can't change it(given the assignment parameters), I was getting a static-non static issue which I'm not quite sure how to fix.

Comment: If the graph is cyclic it could be that you are going in circles because you are not keeping track of which nodes are queued to be searched but not yet marked. You should mark the node on a global level when it is queued

Comment: The Stackoverflow crash happens because this is a recursive method. It is calling itself too many times, causing the program to occupy all the available space on the stack, hence the crash.

Comment: Marking the node on a global level is what I think would fix the problem, but just putting boolean[] marked outside the function is giving me an error since my method is static, and I'm not sure how I can access it without changing the method parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Yup, your issue was indeed because the boolean was being reset in a sense. The resetting was happening in this line:

```
marked = new boolean[g.V()];
```

On this line, you are creating a new boolean array in the new function call, which is distinct from the original array . Then you are checking the new array which does not contain the changes from the old array.

I would recommend that you create a wrapper function that initializes the dfs process, and then pass the array into each call of your dfs function.

If you do not want to add extra parameters, just create a static variable as such outside of the method:

```
private static boolean[] marked;
```

Then initialize it when appropriate

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but I'm not allowed to change the parameters of the dfs function, it can only take in(g,s). Or could I call the function from within dfs that checks the array if that makes sense.

Comment: Ah, I had tried that before just without the static, which I should have realized, but that also made me realize my linked-list would never return more than one int since it was creating a new instance everytime dfs was called.

Comment: I'm still getting a StackOverflow error, and I'm sure its because of          'marked = new boolean[g.V()]; ' I'm just not sure how to not instance it each time I call dfs. I can't put it outside the function since the graph can't be called from there.

Comment: @beginner12345 what's the point of `return ret` if you don't assign your recursive call `dfs(g, i)` to anything?

Comment: @mangusta I would need to be returning my recursive call then, otherwise it just finishes, say one branch and stops?

Comment: @beginner12345 you don't have to return the list, because the node has been added to the list in the function body already. the wrong part is that you re-initialize the list on every recursive call

Comment: Even if you don't have an explicit return statement, when you exit a function, you return to the parent function. Also, you can just access the linked list after you finish your run. (you might need to change the member to `public` to do so)